# Accessibility for Google social sign in button

Tags: accessibility, google-signin

There is a blue *Google Social sign in* button from here
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

that is as you see clickable by mouse.

How to make it clickable by the Enter key?

Adding tabindex is an option to apply focus by using Tab button. At the same time it still won't be clickable by the Enter key.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty straightforward: Use a **button tag** instead of a div tag. The advantage of native HTML buttons regarding accessibility and usability are several:

- A focused button can be activated via the enter or space key. The browser automatically triggers the click event handler attached to the button. No need to attach a keyup event handler via JavaScript.
- A button tag inherently has the ARIA role "button", therefore providing valuable semantic information to screen reader users.
- You can freely style the button via CSS. See the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) for an example.

You can easily adapt [this Google Social Signin Button Example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button?pli=1#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic) to make it accessible. Simply change the element with the id "customBtn" from a div to a button (see screenshot). As the click event handler is attached to this element (see auth2.attachClickHandler method in the example), the button will become operable via enter and space key.

[Screenshot with code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzC2p.jpg)